# Gradle initialization removes external libraries

Tags: jakarta-ee, gradle, intellij-idea, glassfish

I create a new project.

New project > Java Enterprise > Web Application and select JSF, choose my GlassFish installation.

[image: Before]

When i press the play button it works (white page with "Hello world"). But I wan't to add gradle so I can install dependencies.

After i run `gradle init` and re-open Intellij my external libraries are gone...

How can i use the GlassFish libraries in combination with gradle?

Added `compileOnly group: 'javax', name: 'javaee-api', version: '8.0'` to my build.gradle, still gives me errors like given below

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that Intellij is adding these external libraries to the *IDEA* project so Gradle has no knowledge of them. You need to add dependencies to Gradle, so that both Gradle *and* IDEA will know about the dependencies.

Since you are deploying to GlassFish 5, you can add a **provided** dependency on the Java EE 8 API like so:

```
provided group: 'javax', name: 'javaee-api', version: '8.0'
```

This tells Gradle (and the IDE) that it can compile your code against the API, but ***not actually include any implementation libraries*** because they will be already present when you deploy to GlassFish.

Comment: Using `provided ...` gives me a `Could not find method provided() for arguments ...` error

Comment: And `compileOnly` works. But for ex: `<h:outputLabel value="Hello world"/>` gives me cannot resolve symbol